# Firefox incorrectly displays iframe youtube video

Tags: jquery, flash, firefox

I've used the excellent jQuery swiper plugin (http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) to create a scrolling player interface that shows content "slide" by "slide", each slide being an <article>. I need some of the slides to display Youtube video, using the standard <iframe> method. This works well in Safari and Chrome, but in Firefox a strange thing happens. The player interface is 760 pixels wide (it's all inside a <section> element that is assigned that width), and in a narrow window Firefox just shows a black rectangle instead of the Youtube video player. However, if the Firefox window is 1521 pixels wide or wider (i.e., more than twice the width of the player), the Youtube player appears in the right place - but none of the UI is clickable (hover changes do happen though).

Also, if I right-click on the Youtube player in Firefox, the Flash contextual menu appears on my screen over 1,000 pixels to the right of the Flash player.

It's very strange - I've put a demo up at http://backattheranch.ca/matt/player/ for people to poke through. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's the `transform: translate3d();` on the .swiper-wrapper parent element. We ran into a similar problem, and removing that transform on a parent element fixed it.

To recreate that this is the issue affecting you:

1. On your example page, select item #3 -- that has a video.
2. Pop open FireBug, select the div.swiper-wrapper element.
3. In the CSS editor, 'x' out the translate3d on both the element.style, as well as in the .swiper-wrapper class. Your video will disappear, but have no fear! To bring it back and test that this is indeed the issue,
4. Enter the following CSS into the element.style in the FireBug editor:

   `left: -1520px`

Your video will reappear, and you'll see that it's clickable, and plays.

I just had a look at the idangero.us website, and I don't see an update for this issue; looks like their player uses the translate3d transform to slide stuff around. Unfortunately, this means you're going to need to find a different swiper solution that doesn't use the translate3d to position your elements, OR request that they fix this and wait for the fix.

I highly recommend [Malsup's Cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/), if you're stuck for a scroller that supports video. Very extendable, well documented. You can see a [demo of the slider running video, working in Firefox here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/video.php).

In the [Malsup Cycle 2 downloads](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/download/), you'll find there are touch friendly swipe plugins that enable [touch features](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/swipe.php).

We use Cycle 2 on the [Getty's website](http://www.getty.edu/visit/center/art.html), but unfortunately none of our sliders currently display video.